# Dreamweaver and CodeIgniter Design View not working when editing a View page

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, dreamweaver, design-view

when opening a CodeIgniter View file in Dreamweaver Design View (application/views/register.php), the Design View loads only the content in the file (without css), because it tries to open localhost/mysite/application/views/register.php instead of localhost/mysite/register where is the register page with header.php and footer.php loaded before and after register.php (I'm loading these Views from another View called template.php).

So, the question is:
**How to tell Dreamweaver which is the correct url that is must open? Is there something like url rewriting in Dreamweaver?**

Thanks!

Comment: I would never dream of using the design view for that purpose, but cant you just change the css path just while your editing and then change back again?

Comment: Also DW doesnt open an url but opens a file (in design view anyway) so editing combined php files (with includes) wont be possible. I would use a local server instead for the view and then edit the code in code view.

Comment: changing the css path won't work, because I have too many Views that have only <body> content. For now I change the url manually and then hit F5 everytime I change the design or css.